# Is there a way to simplify an undirected graph with OSMNX?

Tags: python, networkx, openstreetmap, graph-theory, osmnx

In my research, I use OpenStreetMap data for traffic-related simulations. Part of the data preparation involves using the *osmnx* library to get a [simplified graph](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/osmnx.html#osmnx.simplification.simplify_graph) of the road network.

Currently, we **do not want to consider one ways.** In other words, every road should be represented as a single edge, regardless of whether or not it's a one-way or two-way street. This essentially means that I am looking to have an undirected graph rather than a directed graph.

The main problem is that osmnx's simplify graph only works with directed graphs.
If I call osmnx's *simplify_graph* function using a MultiDiGraph, I end up with something like this. In this example, the contiguous edges are not being merged because the part in purple is one-way whereas the pink and light blue parts are two-way streets. Relevant OpenStreetMap way IDs are [46678071](https://www.openstreetmap.org/way/46678071), [110711994](https://www.openstreetmap.org/way/110711994) and [237298378](https://www.openstreetmap.org/way/237298378). **However**, this is not what I am looking for; I would like these three edges to be merged, regardless of the fact that one of them is one-way.

[image: problem with graph simplification]

```python
ox.settings.log_console = True
G = ox.graph_from_xml("osm_network_agglomeration_montreal.xml",
                               simplify=False,
                               retain_all=True,
                               bidirectional=False)

# Only retain graph that is inside a certain zone
G = ox.truncate.truncate_graph_polygon(G, boundary_polygon)


# Filter edges based on highway type
allowed_highway_types = ["primary", 
                         "secondary", 
                         "tertiary"]
edges_subset = []
for u, v, data in G.edges(data=True):
    if data['highway'] in allowed_highway_types:
        edges_subset.append((u, v, 0))

G_subset = G.edge_subgraph(edges_subset)

#G_subset = ox.get_undirected(G_subset) # Can't do this as simplify_graph only works with directed graphs.

# Simplify the graph: get rid of interstitial nodes 
G_truncated = ox.simplify_graph(G_subset, strict=True, remove_rings=False)

# Convert to an undirected graph. We don't want parallel edges unless their geometries differ.
G_truncated = ox.get_undirected(G_truncated)

gdf_nodes, gdf_links = ox.graph_to_gdfs(G_truncated)

# Get rid of the variables we won't need anymore
#del G, edges_subset, G_subset
```

So, my question is: is there a way to simplify an **undirected** graph? I am fine with modifying OSMNX's code and submitting a pull request if that's what's required here.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you just create your network as fully bidirectional using the `bidirectional_network_types` setting? https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/osmnx.html#module-osmnx.settings

Comment: @gboeing Hi-that seems to work, thanks. Only thing is that the graph_from_xml function does not seem to consider the `bidirectional_network_types` setting, but rather uses a `bidirectional` parameter directly. In any case, it seems to do that I want need.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to convert the graph to undirected and then back to directed, so that all edges become two-way:

```py
from networkx import Graph, DiGraph, path_graph

G = path_graph(4, create_using=DiGraph)
print(G.is_directed())
# True
print(G.edges)
# [(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3)]

G = DiGraph(Graph(G))
print(G.is_directed())
# True
print(G.edges)
# [(0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 2), (2, 1), (2, 3), (3, 2)]
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your response. @gboeing's comment seems to fix my problem, but this might also have worked. :)