# Change road network to bidirectional in osmnx

Tags: python, osmnx

I wonder if I can set all road networks to bidirectional using osmnx? I hope it is bidirectional rather than undirected because I still hope to use some functions like `osmnx.truncate`. So  `osmnx.get_undirected(G)` cannot help me.

I saw @gboeing mentioned this can be done by changing the [global settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74881392/is-there-a-way-to-simplify-an-undirected-graph-with-osmnx). But I am not sure how to do that. Two questions

1. The global settings are stored in `settings.py` file. How can I create a new file and force `osmnx` uses the new `settings.py`file?
2. If I want to make all edges bidirectional, can I just simply set `bidirectiional_network_types=['all']`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The global settings are stored in `settings.py` file. How can I create a new file and force `osmnx` uses the new `settings.py`file?

You can alter osmnx settings by setting variables within `osmnx.settings`. Example:

```
import osmnx
osmnx.settings.bidirectional_network_types = ["walk", "drive"]
```

> If I want to make all edges bidirectional, can I just simply set bidirectiional_network_types=['all']?

No, that will not work. The network type you are making bidirectional must match the network_type you're using in functions such as [`graph_from_address()`](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/osmnx.html#osmnx.graph.graph_from_address). When it checks the `bidirectional_network_types` list, it checks it in the following fashion:

```
bidirectional = network_type in settings.bidirectional_network_types
```

In other words, the argument `network_type` must exactly match one of the entries inside `bidirectional_network_types` to be treated as a bidirectional network.